# angularjs locationprovider internet explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, angularjs

I'm using angular.js and have trouble with IE8.

It redirects my site from examplepage.local/the/path to examplepage.local/#/the/path and shows a blank page.

I've activated the HTML5Mode

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

It works fine in browsers like chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for angular it says: "Opening a regular URL in a legacy browser -> redirects to a hashbang URL", so this seems to be the expected behaviour.

However, there's some information for you here. One guy did actually solve it and posted a snippet for it.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/XujWvUl0nXg